# Alarm Manager doesn't work for me

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to get the alarm to work, but it doesn't do anything, what do I'm mising? 
My code is

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnetimeAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + 3000, sender);
```

And my broadcast receiver looks like this

```
    public class OnetimeAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Which is an inner class.

What do I'm missing?

Comment: It's better that you move the OnetimeAlarmReceiver to an outer class. It's not working because OnetimeAlarmReceiver (this is an inner class, right?) cannot be instantiated without instantiating the parent class.

Answer (score 7):

You broadcast receiver must be registered in order to work, it can be done either in AndroidManifest.xml or dynamically, using the `Context.registerReceiver()` method.

You can read the developer's guide about registering receviers [statically](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) or check the reference to find out how to do this [dynamically](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: Thank you very much both. I moved it to an outer class and register it in the manifest, now it works great.

Answer (score 2):

This is working code.

Add to Manifest.xml:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
...
```

Code:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {   
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
         wl.acquire();

         // Put here YOUR code.
         Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

         wl.release();
     }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 10), pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }
}
```